# How to change MediaWiki toolbar icon?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm using **MediaWiki version 1.21.3** for internal documentation. I've changed WikiEditor toolbar from the Standard one to an Enhanced editing toolbar.

**Issue:** The icons displayed for Bold and Italics are displayed as **A**, *A*. I would like to change the Bold icon & Italics icon displayed in my Enhanced Edit tool bar to **B**, *I*.

I replaced the value of parameter **icon:** in

> jquery.wikiEditor.toolbar.config

inside the WikiEditor modules from

> 'icon': { 'default': 'format-bold.png', 'en': 'format-bold-B.png',
>   'cs': 'format-bold-B.png', 'de': 'format-bold-F.png', 'fr':
>   'format-bold-G.png', 'gl': 'format-bold-N.png', 'es':
>   'format-bold-N.png', 'eu': 'format-bold-L.png', 'he':
>   'format-bold-B.png', 'hu': 'format-bold-F.png', 'it':
>   'format-bold-G.png', 'ka': 'format-bold-ka.png', 'nl':
>   'format-bold-V.png', 'os': 'format-bold-os.png', 'pt':
>   'format-bold-N.png', 'pt-br': 'format-bold-N.png', 'pl':
>   'format-bold-B.png', 'ru': 'format-bold-ru.png', 'ml':
>   'format-bold-B.png'}

to

> 'icon': 'en': 'format-bold-B.png',

but it does not seem to fix it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Gowri

Comment: This MediaWiki page can perhaps help you: https://mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikiEditor/Toolbar_customization.

Answer (score 0):

First check that the PNG in question actually exists in the assets directory of MediaWiki, then follow the instructions at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikiEditor/Toolbar_customization#Example:_adding_localized_icons as suggested by Suriyaa.